# rails 4 simpecov missing files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simplecov

I am a huge fan of testing and when I run my current coverage reports I noticed that my lib sub folders with .rb files are not being picked up by simplecov.

Here is my setup in my spec_helper.rb file:

```
if ENV['COVERAGE']
  require 'simplecov'
  SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::MultiFormatter[
    SimpleCov::Formatter::HTMLFormatter
  ]
  SimpleCov.minimum_coverage 90
  SimpleCov.start do
    coverage_dir 'tmp/coverage'
    add_filter '/.bundle/'
    add_filter '/spec/'
    add_filter '/config/'
    add_group 'Models', 'app/models'
    add_group 'Controllers', 'app/controllers'
    add_group 'Services', 'app/services'
    add_group 'Helpers', 'app/helpers'
    add_group 'Lib', 'lib'
    add_group 'Mailers', 'app/mailers'
    add_group "Long Files" do |src_file|
      src_file.lines.count > 100
    end
    add_group 'Ignored Code' do |src_file|
      open(src_file.filename).grep(/:nocov:/).any?
    end
  end
end
```

While I do not have much in that folder today, I am trying to figure out why they are not coming in.  Currently, I would have expected to see my `lib/modules` folder in my reports b/c it has a helper_functions.rb file used by rake inside.

=> [the git issue #351](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/351)

Also, I have tried these solutions with no luck:

- [Simple cov gem missing untested files in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075516/simple-cov-gem-missing-untested-files)
- [simplecov not covering lib directory in Rails engine -- NOT a missing require](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/221)
- [SimpleCov with multiple apps - or in short, how does Simplecov work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501607/simplecov-with-multiple-apps-or-in-short-how-does-simplecov-work)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I once had a similar issue and it turned out that some of the unreported code was being loaded before SimpleCov was started. For example, if you are running your tests via a `rake` command, if your Rakefile pulls in some libraries before invoking the spec_helper.rb script, those libraries won't get reported.

Comment: the issue was there were not specs created for the rb file... doh! I did adjust the the rspec install though based on your comment, so I will definitely toss you credit.

Comment: Have the same issue, just check that simplecov init in rails_helper goes before all other stuff

Comment: SimpleCov.start('rails')
      ...
    end

Missing ('rails'), worked for me